# Creating Own Exceptions in Java

Tags: java, exception

```
public class TestExceptions extends Exception {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String test = "no";
        try {
            System.out.println("start try");
            doRisky("no");
            System.out.println("end try");
        } catch( ScaryException se) {
            System.out.println("scaryexception");
        } finally {
            System.out.println( "finally") ;
        }

        System.out.println("end of main");
    }
    static void doRisky(String test) throws ScaryException {
        System.out.println("start risky");
        if ("yes".equals(test)) {
            throw new ScaryException();
        }
        System.out.println("end risky");
        return;
    }
}
```

This code is not working. Errors: can't find symbols. This is the example from Head First Java Book.

If We change the name of the class as ScaryException from TestExceptions, then It is working fine. Why is it so?
Is it necessary to have the class name same as the exception we are throwing in case of customize exceptions.

Comment: yes,is necessary. If you want to use `TestExceptions`, then change this line `throw new TestException();`

Comment: where is this: ***ScaryException*** in your JDK?

Comment: You have to use the same name for the Definition of the class and where you use it. That is not Special for exception. That are programming basics

Comment: Any update for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ScaryException.java

```
public class ScaryException extends Exception {

        public ScaryException(String exceptionMsg){     
            System.out.println("in ScrayException: " +exceptionMsg);
        }
    }
```

Main.java

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "no";  
    try  {  
        System.out.println("start try");  
        doRisky("yes"); 
        System.out.println("end try"); 
        } 
    catch( ScaryException se)  {        
        System.out.println("in catch");  
        }  
    finally  {  
        System.out.println( "finally") ; 
        } 
    System.out.println("end of main");

    }

    static void doRisky(String test) throws ScaryException  {  
        System.out.println("start risky");  
        if ("yes".equals(test))  { 
            throw new ScaryException("Scary Exception thrown from doRisky"); 
            }  
        System.out.println("end risky"); 
        return;  
}

}
```

May be this example would make it clear for you.

Yes, name of custom Exception class and java file should be same. By writing extends Exception, you are creating a custom exception. Hence in your example you were creating TestExceptions, but trying to throw ScaryExceptions which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it necessary to have the class name same as the exception we are
>   throwing in case of customize exceptions

yes, it is necessary.

If you want to use `TestException`, then change this line `throw new TestException();`

You can get more example from [Java Custom Exception](https://www.javatpoint.com/custom-exception)

Answer (score 0):

Seems your assumption is correct. Either there should be a separate Exception class named ScaryException which you missed to add, or the name should be ScaryException instead of TestExceptions. Since TestExceptions is extending Exception, the latter would be the case.